# Unable to show model data from db to template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am unable to show data from django 3rd model(class Jenkinsjobsinformation) to template. It is possible to publish data from the 1st and 2nd model(Projectname and Jenkinsjobsname).Below find my model:

Comment: I don't understand where you are stuck. You know how to use the `{% url %}` tag; you have the `jenkinsjobname` variable available; why can't you just use it?

Comment: I have been trying for one day but not able solve. My problem is here <a href= "#">. I would like set the href link here so that when I click jenkinsjobsname.jobsname} so that it can show the corresponding job information(build/date) from 3rd model. Now It is not showing anything when I click.Please also suggest to do it different way if it is possible.

Comment: You haven't explained what you tried and why you're confused. As I said, you've successfully used `{% url %}` elsewhere; why can't you use it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the method `get_absolute_url` to the model `Jenkinsjobsname`:

```
class Jenkinsjobsname(models.Model):
    projectname=models.ForeignKey(Projectname)
    jobsname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.jobsname

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('job_detail',
                       kwargs={'projectname_id': self.projectname.pk, 'jobinformation_id': self.pk}
```

In the template change the link to:

```
<li><a href="{{jenkinsjobsname.get_absolute_url}}">{{jenkinsjobsname.jobsname}}</a></li>
```

You could do it directly as well, but this way also the Django Admin will pick up the link. `get_absolute_url` is a Django convention: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Comment: Thanks a lot.It is showing now.Is there any way to reduce to one template instead of three template index.html,detail.html and job_detail.html?

Comment: To re-use parts of your templates - use partial templates with `{% include 'my_partial_template.html' %}` - if you really want to use only one single template you have to add state flags to your template context that you can use to decide on which parts to show and which not - unless you can decide that from just checking the objects already present in the context. This is not part of the question - better ask another one or just look trough the Django documention for inspiration.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will ask another question.